# How to get the name of the current Windows user in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I was wondering how I would get the name of the current user in JavaScript as part of an HTML document.

In Java, one would type `System.getProperty("user.name");` to achieve this. What is the alternative to this in JavaScript?

Comment: Current user? It's a huge security risk when that's possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Username in context to what ?

Comment: When you are signed in to your computer, you have a user name. This is what I wish to get.

Comment: How do you expect the current user to be set?  This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript or others (and the answer is generally you can't ... unless you control the server side and want to embed it as javascript or what not) or may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript (note that if I understand at least one of the answers, this won't work unless you're running the javascript as a firefox add on)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

JavaScript runs in the context of the current HTML document, so it won't be able to determine anything about a current user unless it's in the current page or you do AJAX calls to a server-side script to get more information.

JavaScript will not be able to determine your Windows user name.

Comment: How is a server-side script going to get more information about the current user of the client OS?

Comment: You could run a script on localhost...?  I made that suggestion before the poster made the note that he wants the client OS username.

Comment: @DaggNabbit It's pretty common to establish the user's identity on the server side, using SSPI or GSSAPI.

Comment: @SimonBrangwin, never heard of those. Why not add an answer showing how you'd use one of those on a web server to get information like the client's username? I'd be very interested to see how that would work.

Comment: Are we able to get current user name now ?? is there any enhancement in jquery ?? @SurrealDreams

Comment: @thanga - jQuery is still JavaScript.  This is not going to change.

Answer (score 40):

There is no ***fully compatible*** alternative in JavaScript as it posses an unsafe security issue to allow client-side code to become aware of the logged in user.

That said, the following code would allow you to get the logged in username, but it will only work on Windows, and only within Internet Explorer, as it makes use of ActiveX. Also Internet Explorer will most likely display a popup alerting you to the potential security problems associated with using this code, which won't exactly help usability.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Windows Username</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    alert(WinNetwork.UserName); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As *Surreal Dreams* suggested you could use AJAX to call a server-side method that serves back the username, or render the HTML with a hidden input with a value of the logged in user, for e.g.

(ASP.NET MVC 3 syntax)

```
<input id="username" type="hidden" value="@User.Identity.Name" />
```

Comment: I didn't quite undestand the ASP.Net example. Does it get the username that's logged in the .Net system, or the local machine username (that's what the question is about)?

Comment: It depends what authentication mode you use.  If you are using Windows Security option User.Identity.Name will return the Windows username

Answer (score 14):

If the script is running on Microsoft Windows in an HTA or similar, you can do this:

```
var wshshell=new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
var username=wshshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");
```

Otherwise, as others have pointed out, you're out of luck. This is considered to be private information and is not provided by the browser to the javascript engine.

Comment: The browser does indeed have access to the system's username (or any system info for that matter) - however, the browser doesn't expose that to the JS engine.

Answer (score 8):

I think is not possible to do that. It would be a huge security risk if a browser access to that kind of personal information

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Windows login from the USERNAME environment variable.

```
process.env.USERNAME
```

Answer (score -3):

Working for me on IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
  document.write(WinNetwork.UserName);
</script>
```

...but ActiveX controls needs to be on in security settings.

Comment: This doesn't really add any information that http://stackoverflow.com/a/9518490/1089331 doesn't already cover