# get the logged username in windows from a remote server

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

How to get the logged username in windows from a remote server `Apache/jboss`.

I have deployed a war file in tomcat apache which is in `host_1`. I am accessing the web application from `host_2`. `host_2` windows machine and logged in as a testuser. `host_1` is a unix machine.

I want the server application to get the logged in username of windows[testuser] when i hit the request in browser. Is this possible? Do i need to do any settings in my browser?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the internet is anonymous and there the user name is not returned as a http header.

You would need to run some javascript on the users browser to determine the username - and as it is a security risk I dont think it will work very well

I found this link

[JavaScript - How to get the name of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user)