# How to pull window`s login id in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am using a google apps script and writing a script for my google spreadsheet. I need to take the windows login id so that I can know who is filling up the spreadsheet. 
All my searches in the web yield the code that looks like this:

```
var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
alert(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"));
```

But google apps throws an error saying ActiveX not found. I am new to JavaScript and Google Apps.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible nor should it be as it would be a huge security issue.

Explains more: [JavaScript - How to get the name of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user)

Reason it doesn't work on windows in explorer is because your google-apps-script code get sanitized by google-caja.