# Is it possible to detect OS username with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, operating-system, sandbox

Web browsers run in low-permission, sandboxed mode to ensure that they can’t do much damage if they’re compromised, and thus, accessing OS properties is not possible. However, can I request user's permission and somehow access the data I need *(in my case the OS user)*? For instance, browser cannot view the webcam without a permission.

Comment: No in any portable way. On Windows you can use ActiveX to get it, and you can find a number of SO questions that show how to do it.

Comment: For instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user

Comment: That's specific for Windows, but not other operating systems.

Comment: ActiveXObject is available only in IE