# To get Windows username of the client pc when he runs the url

Tags: java

Hi I am working on a module in Java web application where I have to get username of the active windows user on the remote pc, I had used a couple of existing method such as:

1. `System.getenv().get("USERNAME");`
2. `com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem nsys = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem(); nsys.getName();`
3. `request.getUserPrincipal();`
4. `System.getProperty("user.name")`

but all giving the username of the server.

Comment: Is there any solution for my above query

Comment: Yes, but they all require active directory integration (or some other form of identity federation, etc).

Comment: *"all giving the username of the server"* Of course, because you're running that code on the server. Your app is a webapp, i.e. Java code on server, JavaScript code in Web Browser on client, and you want client user, so why do you think server-side Java code is the solution? The only code that can find the client user, is code on the client machine, i.e. JavaScript code in the browser. You could use authorization features to ask the browser to auto-login, like Elliott said, but that's way beyond just getting to know the user name.

Comment: See [JavaScript - How to get the name of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9518092/5221149)

Comment: Does the user have to authenticate so we can get his/her username or it can be done directly

Comment: using active directory

Comment: Hi Elliott is it possible to get windows username using active directory without requiring the user to authenticate  in java web application

Comment: Hi Andreas Javascript does not work on all browsers and it requires the permission of the user to get the username