# Need to capture the windows logged in username

Tags: windows, angular

once the user logged into his windows machine and he opens up our application I need to take his windows credential (username) and just opens up the application home page skipping the login page of the application.I don't want to ask the user to enter username and password again in the login page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - How to get the name of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user)

Answer (score -1):

you can use variable

```
%username%
```

to get windows userusername
Aroly7

Comment: The question is for angular environment