# I want to get client's windows logged in username in angular 6 application without server side

Tags: typescript, angular6

when a client will access my application like(http://website.com). when application will load on client's browser, client's windows username should be displayed on welcome page. i want to get client's windows username using typescript. i don't have server side is there anyone that can help me for my project.

Comment: Maybe helpful [JavaScript - How to get the name of the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user)

Comment: using windows authentication is possible but how to implement it end to end is entirely beyond the scope of a SO post. Try something and come back with specific questions. recommend starting here: https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angular-4-3-1-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/

Comment: @bryan60 we will implement windows authentication on server side and server is not deployed on same computer so when i try to get logged in username it will return the username of computer that is hosting server not client.

Comment: post a specific question with CODE