# How do I get the current client windows username using Vaadin 7?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, vaadin7

I am developing a web application using Vaadin 7 in which I need client windows username. What is the best possible way to get client windows username?

I have tried the following code System.getProperty("user.name") but it return server windows user name.

Comment: AFAIK Vaadin runs on the server and that's why `System.getProperty` won't work. If you need anything from the client side, you'll have to make the client send it. You could have people log in, and collect their user name that way.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
I would also like to know, using JavaScript is there any other way to get the client username from Chrome browser?

Comment: Late to the party, but if I understood correctly what you were trying to do, browser security features prevent querying this information. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-windows-user-in-javascript