# Reading the certifcate information of a web page

Tags: ssl, certificate

Suppose I visit a web page `www.example.com` and is successfully loaded into my browser.

When this page is loaded, we can see the certificate information `www.example.com` by clicking on padlock icon (on left side of address).

The certificate includes the information like owner/organisation, connection status, certificate verified by, cookies set by the page and so on.

Is there any way to get this information programmatically from the browser like by using `javascript/Ajax` or any other language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get SSL certificate details using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link very helpful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/How_to_check_the_secruity_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL