# What HTTP code do you get if an SSL has expired?

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, ssl-certificate, fetch-api

I have a custom monitor code setup. I need to check if the specified URL has its SSL certificate expired. Is there a specific HTTP code for this? For example:

```js
(async() => {
    const res = await fetch('http://example.com');
    // Or `statusText`
    if (res.status == some_ssl_expiryCode) {
        console.log('SSL expired!');
    }
})();
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: No code. The connection might not even get established between client and server.

Comment: So do I check for errors, like putting in a try-catch block or checking if the promise was rejected?

Comment: See the responses here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript

Comment: @Jasen I've seen other services do this, how do they do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Jasen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030565/jasen) said, the connection doesn't reach the server. The `fetch` request returns the error `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` or `CERT_INVALID`. It does not produce an HTTP code. See the javascript code below.

```js
fetch('https://example.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(() => { /* Do something if success */ })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        if (error.code === 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED') {
            // Certificate has expired
        } else if (error.code === 'CERT_INVALID') {
            // Certificate is invalid
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The client application receives an HTTP 400 - Bad request response with the message "The SSL certificate error".

Comment: No it does not.